# POSTGIS - Possible to merge network lines, such that each result represents one connected set?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Essentially, if we have a network of flow lines that represent many tiny sub basins, is there a way to merge each subset with one another such that the resulting output has a single multi line feature for each tiny sub basin?  We're looking to associate each segment with a value that is only present on the further downstream terminal segments of each group.

Curious if there is a solution that works like a dissolve in Arc that uses no attributes, but instead of dissolving all together, it would only group those that touch / flow into one another.

I've seen some solutions posted that work if there is an identifying attribute value per group, but if we had that, we could just do it in Arc also.

The best solution I've come up with so far (we have to_node and from_node values) is to loop through, tracing each segment to its eventual related terminal downstream segment.  This takes some time for sure and I feel there's got to be a better way out there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Perhaps I've overlooked something simple.  Thanks in advance!

Here is what is currently running. Please note that the line set is called "lines_4326", I am using a field called "PARENT" to trace down toward terminal to_node values, and "line_ends" is a table hold just the to_node values of the terminal segments (as in, there are NO from_node values in the set that = the values in that list).

> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "TRACE_DOWN"() RETURNS void AS $$ DECLARE
>
> count_left integer;
>
> BEGIN
>
> UPDATE lines_4326 SET "PARENT" = to_node; SELECT COUNT(gid) FROM
>   lines_4326 WHERE "PARENT" NOT IN (SELECT to_node from line_ends) INTO
>   count_left;
>
> WHILE count_left > 0 LOOP
>
> UPDATE lines_4326 SET "PARENT" = b.to_node FROM lines_4326 b WHERE
>   lines_4326."PARENT" = b.from_node;
>
> SELECT COUNT(gid) FROM lines_4326 WHERE "PARENT" NOT IN (SELECT
>   to_node FROM lines_4326 WHERE "IS_END" = '1') INTO count_left;
>
> END LOOP;
>
> END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE

Comment: Have you got some code for what you've already tried that you can show us?

Comment: Isn't ST_Union making all the job??

Comment: It's difficult to tell from the question, but you can use a `WITH RECURSIVE` query in place of a loop, testing if the end of one line segment touches another. This would populate your `to_node` IDs.

Comment: @MikeT. I wondered the same thing, but the question seems simpler than the code sample?

Comment: @MikeT.  Luckily I already have the to and from nodes populated as a result of the initial creation of the geometric network.  The code sample I copied in above serves simply to use those existing values to trace every segment all the way 'downstream'.  That gives me a value on which to dissolve in Arc.  Its just rather time consuming for 1M+ features.  I had posted the question hoping there was a simple solution to grab all features in related networks at once and put a tag on them without having to trace in such a way.  Thank you for taking an interest in helping me find a solution :)

Answer (score 4):

Hy,
I know it's an old post but... maybe it will help someone else

So, searching a solution for something like ZFlyGuy's problem, I found this (here : [https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=71450](http://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=71450))

```
select (st_dump(st_linemerge(st_union(the_geom)))).geom from lines;
```

It's part of the solution for me

Maybe this we'll also help but I did not read it already : https://github.com/Oslandia/presentations/raw/master/pgconf_eu_2012/pgconfeu2012_vincent_picavet_postgis_topology.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) in conjunction with [ST_Dump](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html). ST_Dump will break the results of ST_Union into individual (Multi) Linestrings.

```
Select (ST_Dump(ST_Union(line))).geom from Lines_4326;
```

assuming that your line segments are called line.

Because ST_Dump is a set returning function, it returns a row and a geometry, so you need to use the syntax (ST_Dump(geomcoll)).geom to get the constituent geometries. ST_Union is the equivalent of Dissolve in the Arc world and does not require any attributes to work. It will return a geometry collection, a multi geometry or a single geometry, depending on the input, but in your case, it will return a geometry collection made up of (multi) linestrings.

To view the output in certain tools, QGIS for example, you will want to have an id field for each distinct geometry, which can be accomplished by using row_number() over(), eg,

```
Select row_number() over() as id, (ST_Dump(ST_Union(line))).geom from Lines_4326;
```

**EDIT** Following a comment from the OP about the efficiency of this approach, note [this blog article](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2009/01/must-faster-unions-in-postgis-14.html) from Paul Ramsey (creator of Postgis) about cascading unions and efficient use of the index as the union is being built.

Comment: I know the answer seems very simple, so I am wondering did I misunderstand the question? What you ask for doesn't get very well with your code sample, which is why I ask.

Comment: Hi John.  It very well may be that simple.. but will this efficiently work when I have several million lines?  I do not have an attribute on which to base the Union, and have not been able to find a way to flag all features within the distinct networks in a common way to give me an attribute.  If I understand correctly, you method would union all lines, and then dump would break them into the separate related families?  Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a blog article I read a few years ago about this exact subject, noting that the index is used to intelligently union geometries together. Ultimately, there is no substitute for trying it out and seeing how performance goes.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?